# shared_ptr memory leak without delete operator

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I have implemented a simple struct:

```
struct ListenerNode
{
    ListenerNode() : previous(nullptr), next(nullptr), listener(nullptr), once(false) {}
    std::shared_ptr<ListenerNode> previous;
    std::shared_ptr<ListenerNode> next;
    std::function<void(int)> listener;
    bool once;
};
```

And this is going to represent an entity in a scenegraph implementation. The wierd behavior that I am observing is that when I use the struct simply like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ListenerNode n;
}
```

It leaks memory but when I use it like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ListenerNode* n = new ListenerNode();
    delete n;
}
```

It does not leak memory! I don't understand what's going on here. I always thought making an instance of a class/struct without `new` calls the destructor immediately when the variable goes out of scope.

Could someone please explain to me what's going on here? I don't see any obvious reference increment neither.

Comment: how do you know it is leaking?

Comment: `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`

Comment: Where do you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`?

Comment: What if you enclose `ListenerNode n;` with an extra pair of braces?

Comment: @RSahu Right before closing `main`'s bracket and after the operation shown above.

Comment: At that point `n` is not destructed yet.

Comment: @timrau it actually does not leak with an extra pair of braces! now a third case added to my confusion list!

Comment: There's no confusion. Without the extra set of braces, you're calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` before the lifetime of `n` has ended. Obviously the destructor hasn't run yet in that case. By adding the braces and calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` after the closing brace, the lifetime of `n` has ended. In the `new`+`delete` cause you're controlling the lifetime manually.

Comment: add a scope, you will see the difference `int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  {  ListenerNode n; }
}`

Comment: That actually fixed it! I can't believe I was modifying my source for 2 hours to fix a non-existing memory leak!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your comment, you test for memory leak as in the following snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    ListenerNode n;
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

In this case, at the time `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` is called, `n` is not out-of-scope yet. You can definitely access the content of `n` after `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` without any problem. `n` is destructed after the closing brace of `main()` is encountered.

If you add an extra pair of braces:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    { ListenerNode n; }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Then, `n` is destructed right when the extra closing brace is encountered. At the time you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`, `n` is not accessible at all since it's already out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You will leak memory if you create a list with your class. Never create cycles (as you do with next/previous) with shared_ptr, they will not delete anything.

You do not need to initialise shard_ptr with nullptr.